# $route.reload() does not work with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've switched to to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Everything went smoothly, except one thing. On my page I have a select that changes the context of the application. Anyway, previously, when this context was changed I was executing this code (in particular, **set** method):

```
'use strict';
angular.module('main').factory('lacContext', ['$route', function ($route) {
    return {
        set: function (id) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("lac-context", id);
            $route.reload();
        },
        get: function () {
            return sessionStorage.getItem("lac-context");
        }
    };
}])
```

and

```
$route.reload()
```

was doing the most important thing. It reloaded the page. But after switching to ui-router, $route.reload does nothing. Also I did not find counterpart in ui-router API. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `$state.go('.')`?

Comment: Nope. How can I access current state?

Comment: You need to inject the `$state` service as you do `$route` then you can call this method. See documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: I did it and $state is undefined

Comment: If you have inject the ui-router dependency in module correctly you would get the $state object. See this wiki link with examples https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: I have dependency set. Otherwise other features would not work

Comment: Hold your horses. I'll implement it this weekend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok it works when I inject $state into controller.

But when injecting it into service like code snippet, of course $state was undefined.

Although

```
$state.go('.')
```

did not work, I did something like this:

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
          controller: function ($state) {
              $state.go('advisoryLeadOffering.packages');
          }
      })
      .state('advisoryLeadOffering.packages', {
          url: "/packages",
          templateUrl: "/AdvisoryLeadOffering/Packages",
          controller: 'AdvisoryLeadOfferingPackages'
      })
```

and when I need to reload I do something like this:

```
$state.transitionTo('home');
```

inside scope's method.

Answer (score 37):

How about:

```
$state.go($state.$current, null, { reload: true });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $state.go($state.current, null, { reload: true }); ?

Answer (score 8):

You can do `$state.reload()`

There's a bug with it sometimes not re-instantiating the controller.
You can get around that with

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted a link outside of the controller to refresh a state and just created a `reload()` function in the controller.

`SomeCtrl`:

```
$scope.reload = function(){
    $state.transitionTo('myState');
}
```

Add this to your anchor:

```
ng-click="reload()"
```

H/T @dragonfly for pointing me to `transitionTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing worked for me:

**Create redirect state:**

```
$stateProvider.state('redirect', {
    url: 'redirect/:to',
    controller: function($state, $stateParams, $scope) {
        $state.go($stateParams.to, null, {reload: true});
    }
});
```

**Go to this state:**

```
$state.go('redirect', {to: $state.current.name}, {reload: true});
```