# angular-ui router reload view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using angular-ui's router (v0.2.0) in a project and we're trying to reload a view.  I've tried `$state.transitionTo` and also `$state.go`, but neither seem to do anything.  Would anyone know how to do a reload?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The 3rd parameter of `$state.go` takes an options object which has a reload property, so doing something like

```
$state.go('resources', {start: $stateParams.start}, {reload:true});
```

Should do the trick - on the latest version I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using v 0.2.5

This is working .  <kbd>$state.reload()</kbd>

[Reference Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statereload)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular UI route v0.2.5, there is a third parameter `reload`

```
  $state.transitionTo(to, toParams [, options])
  $state.go(to, toParams [, options])
```

Third parameter is optional.

```
  $state.go('contacts', {sort: 'name' }, { reload: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going from state A to state A again, the internals of the angular-ui would forbid it from reloading the state. You'd have to go to a different state to have a reload. That is to avoid clicking many times on the same link issuing a reload.

You can try switching to the same state, but with slightly different params, if you are that desperate to reissue a reload. But in my point of view, if you are in the same state, a reload shouldn't happen.

There is already also a similar question on SO:
[$route.reload() does not work with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583170/route-reload-does-not-work-with-ui-router)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using grunt and building yourself there is a new $state.reload() feature. Or you can wait until v0.3 coming soonish.

Answer (score 0):

Comment on similar question [Reloading current state - refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data) by SimplGy:

> Probably worth noting that none of these [edit: meaning $state.transitionTo('state'), $state.reload() or $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true})] actually reload the page as
>   well. If you want to reload the state AND the page, there is no
>   ui-router method for it I think. Do window.location.reload(true)

Another comment by edhedges improved this one by mentioning the use of

```
$window.location.reload()
```

Which works and I recommend using for the reloading a ui-view.