# MEAN.js Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack, meanjs

I want to reload page after update, so `$location.path('route');` doesn't work. I have found, that `$route.reload();` might work, but not in MEAN.js, because an application throws following error:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

I think, it's because of absence ngRoute in MEAN.js, because it uses ui-router ... so how can I reaload a page? (`'$route'` dependency was added to controller of course)

Comment: You need to use $state with ui.router, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583170/route-reload-does-not-work-with-ui-router

Comment: thanks, this navigated me to solution: `$state.go('.', {param: $param}, {reload: true});`